# Why have many util.is* functions been deprecated in node.js v4.0.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js

As node v4.0.0 has been released. This version of node deprecated many functions like `util.isArray`, `util.isRegEx`, util.`isDate`, `util.isBoolean` and many others.

I want to know why this happened to node?

Is there native support of these things in ES6?

Or does node provide any better solution instead of these things?

Comment: If you see [changelog](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.0.0/CHANGELOG.md#20140501-version-01113-unstable) `util: made util.isArray a direct alias for Array.isArray (Evan Carroll)`. node was calling JS function directly, so no need to keep alias, call the native function directly

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The decision to deprecate the `util.is*()` functions was initially made at a Node.js Technical Steering Committee (TSC) in April 2015. Well, at that point in time, it was still io.js, but the same committee is now the Node.js TSC and the code base they were talking about is what became Node.js 4.0.0.

The [minutes from the meeting](https://github.com/nodejs/TSC/blob/master/meetings/io.js/2015-04-08.md) are online. So you can read it yourself to see the pros and cons that were weighed. The clearest statement of the issue in those minutes might be from Bert Belder:

> The reason we want to deprecate these is that we don’t really want to fix it because that would be backward incompatible, so this is really too big to be in core.

(Unfortunately, there seems to be some missing context in the minutes. I'll see if I can dig up some more context from other sources and, if I find anything useful, I'll update this answer.)

UPDATE: Judging from some [TSC minutes from February](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v1.x/doc/tc-meetings/2015-02-18.md#util-fixed-behavior-of-isobject-822--chrisdickinson--major-version-release) and [discussion in a pull request from the same month](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/822), it seems like the reasoning is something like this:

*Hey, looks like `util.isObject()` returns `false` for a function. That isn't correct. A function is an object. It should return `true`. But making that change potentially breaks huge portions of the Node ecosystem. Think of all those modules on npm that might be dependent on that behavior. In order to not risk breaking the ecosystem in surprising ways, we'd have to somehow get a ton of people to review their code. And the breaking change would be totally backwards incompatible. All for a convenience function that doesn't even really belong in core and is easily provided by userland modules. (See, for example, [core-util-is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-util-is).) Rather than introduce a breaking change and a semver major bump just to fix `util.isObject()`, let's do what should have been done in the first place and don't even have it in core.*

I think there may have also been a sense that there were likely other corner cases lurking in the `util.is*()` functions.

The philosophy of the project in general is to have a minimal core. All things being equal, if something can be provided by userland modules without too much trouble, it ought to live in userland modules and not core.

OK, that's me drawing a lot of inferences from some bits of text, but I think that's more or less what's up with the deprecation.

Comment: *"Hey, looks like util.isObject() returns false for a function. That isn't correct. A function is an object. It should return true"*  But the [recommended replacement](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_isfunction_object) is `typeof value === 'function`.  How does that in any way improve on the speakers complaint?  `typeof f === "object"` when `f` is a function is still `false`.  What does the speaker mean when they say *"A function is an object. "*?  I understand it is conceptually so, because a function has state. But that has nothing to do with `typeof` syntax. Foolish deprecations.

Comment: @CraigHicks A function is not merely conceptually an object. In JavaScript, `Object` is in the prototype chain for `Function`. A function, literally, is an instance of an object. If `f` is a function, then `f instanceof Object` is `true`. So whether `util.isObject(f)` should return `true` or `false` in that case is not a simple issue to resolve, and it's not clear what the best and most ergonomic choice is. Therefore, it is better left to the user. The suggestion in the docs to use `typeof` is if the user wants to preserve the functionality of `isFunction()`.

Comment: Good point.   I still don't agree with the solution though.  Providing better function names - utils.isTypeofFunction, utils.isTypeofObjectNonNull etc. would allow a simple text replace over projects to enable compliance immediately.  Those new names would become universal, whereas when moved to userland there will be different names or same names with different implementations, all of which will serve to slow down development as developers either misinterpret the userland functions or write out the longhand.  Frankly, I believe just clearly documenting the behavior of existing funcs is best.

Answer (score 2):

Not a `node.js` expert, but these functions (if they do what the name says) can be easily replaced by

```js
[] instanceof Array; // true
/* or */ Array.isArray([]); // true

(/(?:)/g) instanceof RegExp; // true

new Date() instanceof Date; // true

new Boolean(true) instanceof Boolean; // true
/* or */ typeof false == 'boolean';
/* or even */ var bool1 = true, bool2 = false;
!!bool1 === bool1; // true
!!bool2 === bool2; // true
```

According to [the changelog](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.0.0/CHANGELOG.md#notable-changes):

> The `util.is*()` functions have been deprecated, beginning with deprecation warnings in the documentation for this release, users are encouraged to seek more robust alternatives in the npm registry.

They link this [pull request](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/2447) that contains some of the reasoning which leads to [this dialog](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/tsc-meetings/io.js/2015-04-08.md#1301-utilis-deprecations), stating:

> The reason we want to deprecate these is that we don’t really want to fix it because that would be backward incompatible, so this is really too big to be in core.

In short, these functions were buggy in some sense and instead of fixing the bugs and breaking backward compatibility, they decided to deprecate them instead.

If you really need to check these things often enough, you can write your own functions for that, if you wish.

Comment: I think you're not answering the real question. `Why many functions deprecated from util in node new version v4.0.0?`

Comment: @Tushar Yes, but it’s a partial answer, answering _“Is there native support of these things in ES6?”_, which is [okay](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). You can always edit my answer or contribute your own. My answer is in no way wrong or bad, only because it’s not complete.

Comment: You can add this http://toddmotto.com/understanding-javascript-types-and-reliable-type-checking/ for type checking. Scroll to the bottom