# TSLint autofix deprecations from util

Tags: typescript, tslint

I'm wondering if there's a way in VSCode to autofix deprecations from the `util` library.

Example:

```js
if (isNullOrUndefined(this.api)) {
```

Should be:

```js
if (this.api === null || this.api === undefined) {
```

There is no autofix option, only a rule disablement option... but the hovertext shows the fix!

Comment: This seems like a very special case where a deprecation has a one-to-one replacement.

Comment: @AluanHaddad it's not though, there are *many* newly deprecated functions like this from the utils lib. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515413/why-have-many-util-is-functions-been-deprecated-in-node-js-v4-0-0)

Comment: `isNull`, `isNullOrUndefined`, `isString`, `isObject` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The autofixes you see in VS Code come from TSLint. Auto fixing deprecated apis is not supported currently and would require a fix in TSLint itself.

The complete list of auto-fixable tslint rules is [here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/) (auto fixable ones are indicated by `has-fixer`)

---

To replace these node apis, the safest change would be to write your own `isNullOrUndefined` function (or find one from npm) and switch all callers to use it instead of the node version